# What is the relationship between the characteristic polynomial of a product vs. the product of characteristic polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What is the relationship between the characteristic polynomial of two square matrices and the characteristic polynomial of the product of these two square matrices? If I know the characteristic polynomials of each one of these matrices, what can I say about the characteristic polynomial of their product?
I can't seem to find this information anywhere.

Thank you!

Comment: You can't say anything. For example, if $A$ is any invertible matrix, then $AA^{-1}$ has characteristic polynomial $(1-x)^n$. However, if you take any matrix $B$ similar to $A^{-1}$, this has the same characteristic polynomial of $A^{-1}$, but the product $AB$ could be anything.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the matrices are such that $AB=BA$: one can put both matrices in triangular form within the same basis $(e_i)$ should this condition be satisfied. Call $\lambda_i$ (resp. $\mu_i$) the eigenvalues of $A$ and (resp. $B$) associated with eigenvector $e_i$. Then the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $AB$ i.e. the eigenvalues of this matrix are the products $\lambda_i\mu_i$ of the roots of the characteristic polynomials $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_i$ of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I don't understand: if you take all the products of a root of $A$ with a root of $B$, you end up with $n^2$ roots...

Comment: Sorry, not clear enough, I'll edit the answer...

Comment: Maybe you mean that you order the eigenvalues (by increasing order of their absolute value ?) and take the products in that order ?

Comment: For a common basis $(e_i)$ where $A$ and $B$ are triangular, I call $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_i$ the eigenvalues associated with the eigenvector $e_i$.

Comment: Edited my initial answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general there is no nice relation. The product of nilpotent matrices need not be nilpotent (for example, consider the product of a nontrivial nilpotent Jordan block with its transpose), so the characteristic polynomial of the product of two matrices whose characteristic polynomials have only $0$ as a root can have a nonzero root.

Comment: What if there are constraints on the matrices? Say one is positive definite and the other is indefinite?

Comment: Or the relationship could be in their sign, say when the product of the coefficients of each are negative the coefficients of the product are negative/positive?

Comment: If you put constraints on the matrices involved, e.g. they commute, or both are positive semidefinite, or etc., then something more can be said, but you need to state a particular question before one can be answered.